# there will be minds that remain blank and spines that remain unkindled

Tags: meaning, metaphors

> *Of course, no matter how keenly, how admirably, a story, a piece of music, a picture
>   is discussed and analyzed,* ***there will be minds that remain blank and spines that
>   remain unkindled.***

This is the first sentence of Nabokov's Lecture on Metamorphosis. If I understand it good, the author wants to say that there is not possible to fully analyze the particular work of art. But I am not sure with the highlighted part of the sentence. What does it exactly mean ***there will be minds that remain blank and spines that remain unkindled***? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there will be minds that remain blank and spines that remain unkindled

A *blank mind* is an empty mind; in our case, empty of thoughts and questions that the author wished his work would beget in the mind of the reader or the listerer or the viewer. A suberb analysis not always helps fill an empty mind.

An *unkindled spine* refers to the lack of the visceral feeling of excitement sometimes emerging under the influence of a piece of music, or a poem, or a passage in a book. A superb analysis not always helps such a feeling to arise.

When one wants to say that a piece of music has excited him, he says sometimes that it has "sent shivers (tingles) down my spine". A quote from "[Psychology for Musicians](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vW2IV5TNM9IC&lpg=PA219&dq=music%20%22down%20the%20spine%22&hl=ru&pg=PA219#v=onepage&q=music%20%22down%20the%20spine%22&f=false)":

> Everybody has at one point or other experienced strong physiological experiences when listening to music. *Shivers down the spine*, hairs standing on end, tears, "butterflies in the stomach"..

Nabokov says that any work of art or fiction, no matter how superbly it is discussed and analyzed, rouses no thoughts and stirs no emotions in some members of the audience. Rather than say bluntly "no thoughts and no emotions", Vladimir Nabokov employs the metaphors of "blank minds" and "unkindled spines".

Using the literary terminology, we can say that "blank minds and unkindles spines" are **[synecdoches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)** for "members of the audience left emotionally and/or mentally unaffected by the author's work despite the discussion and the analysis".

Nabokov only mentions their minds and spines, but that is enough within the scope of his sentence, as it is enough to say "hired hands" instead of "workers hired to perform manual labor" in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the author wants to express that no matter how well and with how much effort something is analyzed and discussed, there will still be a number of people who won't (be able to) benefit from that at all / won't be interested in it.

This could be for a variety of reasons: Not caring, simply not being able to gain satisfaction from that sort of thing or simply not having the intellectual capacities to take part in and benefit from such a discussion. That's just to name a few.